# Angular Google Maps Markers - Different property name for longitude and latitude

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3, angular-google-maps

I am building a very straight forward map using angular-google-maps. The data I have to work with uses different names for the id and lat/long properties than what Angular Google Maps expects. The API doc refers to the idKey parameter for specifying an alternate id key, this is working fine for me. I have not been able to find a way to pass a parameter to specify an alternate lat/long key. Does anyone know if this is possible?

JSON Example:

```
{
"myId":1, 
"lat":33.00000, 
"long":-82.00000
}
```

Angular Markup:

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom'>
    <ui-gmap-markers models="myModel" idKey="'myId'" coords="'self'" 
       doCluster="'true'" fit="'true'" icon="'icon'">
    </ui-gmap-markers>
</ui-gmap-google-map>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. The ui-gmap looks specifically for latitude and longitude.

Comment: The API was changed to send back "Latitude" and "Longitude". Thanks Myles.